# Windows batch if statement influenced by statements in the if block

Tags: if-statement, batch-file

When I execute the following Windows batch script on Windows Server 2012:

```
@echo off
SET v=()
IF 1 == 2 (
  echo hi
  echo %v:~0%
  echo 1 equals 2
) ELSE (
  echo 1 does not equal 2
)


IF 1 == 2 (
  echo %v:0%
  echo 1 equals 2
) ELSE (
  echo 1 does not equal 2
)
```

I get the following output:

```
1 equals 2
1 does not equal 2
1 does not equal 2
```

Can anybody tell me why this happens? I don't want to go into the block starting with `echo hi` even if the value of v is ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your intention is, but here's how I think your issue can be fixed.

The variable `%v%` is parsed before the `IF` command is run, and that contains a problematic closing parenthesis. What happens therefore is that the code reads, `echo %v:~0%` as `echo (` and closes the `IF` with `)` It then parses the next line which is `echo 1 equals 2`, and prints it as expected.

To prevent that, either escape that parenthesis, when you define that variable:

```sh
@echo off
SET "v=(^)"
IF 1 == 2 (
  echo hi
  echo %v:~0%
  echo 1 equals 2
) ELSE (
  echo 1 does not equal 2
)


IF 1 == 2 (
  echo %v:0%
  echo 1 equals 2
) ELSE (
  echo 1 does not equal 2
)
```

Or, better still enable delayed expansion, so that the variable content is not parsed before the command is run, only when it is:

```sh
@echo off
SET "v=()"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
IF 1 == 2 (
  echo hi
  echo !v:~0!
  echo 1 equals 2
) ELSE (
  echo 1 does not equal 2
)


IF 1 == 2 (
  echo !v:0!
  echo 1 equals 2
) ELSE (
  echo 1 does not equal 2
)
```